# How to create second pull request and ignore all previous commits

Tags: git, branch, pull-request

**What I have:**

Two branches `branch1` and `branch2` for different features, in `branch1` I pushed `5` commits and created pull-request and waiting for code review. 
Then I done with new feature in `branch2` and pushed `3` new commits in second one.

**The Problem:**

When I'm going to create new pull request from `branch2` I see that all `8` commits will be added to this request. And for some reasons I can asked to pull only those `3` from `branch2`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems the branches moved on like this: `branch1` was created from a base commit, 5 new commits were made, `branch2` was created from the tip of `branch1`, 3 more new commits were made. If so, `branch2` should have been created from the base commit too. You could rebase the 3 new commits onto the base commit, or create `branch3` from the base now and then cherry-pick the 3 commits. At last create a new pull request from `branch3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option you can try is:

(I) Once you have done `5` commits to `branch1`, push it to remote for code review.

(II) Checkout to `branch2`, if you enter `git log` you should see the previous `5` commits to `branch1`. Do a `git reset --hard HEAD~5`, which will turn your local repo `5` commits back. You need not worry about permanently losing those `5` commits, since they are available on the remote repo's `branch1` - you can pull it whenever necessary.

(III) Make the changes on your `branch2`, create a new pull request for your `branch2` and push those `3` commits to remote `branch2` for code review. Now, the previous `5` commits will not be included in your new pull request.

Note: This option can be used when the two branches are working on separate features and do not depend on each other's updates to work.
I hope this answers your question. Let me know if you have any issue.

Also, when you want the branches to be separate, right when you are creating the new branch, do a `git checkout master` and then `git checkout -b branch2` so that`branch2` is created from master's history, and not `branch1` or your working branch. Then the branch commits will not overlap with each other, and will follow from master. So in your case, you will then have `5` commits following `branch1` and `3` commits following `branch2` respectively.

Comment: hey, your comment was useful, so I have deleted `branch2` (`stash` all before it) and before create new one used `git checkout` and it helped!

Comment: @kyxap glad it helped :)